# jQuery taking a <img src> in <a> tag to variable

Tags: jquery, attributes, hyperlink, element, src

I want to write to var adres a src value of an img in rollovereed  element

structure is:

```
<div>
 <a class="link" href="#">
    <img src="value" />
 </a>
 <a class="link" href="#">
   <img src="value" />
 </a>
</div>
```

ive tried

```
$('.link').mouseover(function () {
    var adres = ('.link a:first-child').attr('src');
```

but it dosnt workout

Comment: you don't need to look for .link again within the event-function: just go $(this).children().first().attr('src')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.link').mouseover(function() {
     var adres = $('img',this).attr('src');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always display the first link's src attribute. Also, you want to select the 'img' afterwards, not the 'a' like you are doing now. Use it like this:

```
$('.link').mouseover(function () {
    var adres = $(this).find('img').attr('src'); 
});
```